# What does this notation mean: $\displaystyle\lim_{\leftarrow} \,\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$?

Tags: group-theory, notation, field-theory, galois-theory, finite-fields

Just a small notation question from [this Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_Galois_group):

> The absolute Galois group of a finite field $K$ is isomorphic to the group  $$\hat{\mathbb{Z}}=\lim_{\leftarrow} \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}.$$

What does the $\displaystyle\lim_{\leftarrow}$ part mean?  Why is it written like that?

Comment: It's the inverse limit (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_limit).  If you have a copy of Dummit and Foote, the construction is outlined very nicely in some of the excercises.

Comment: Mild terminological rant: I am not a fan of this "inverse limit / direct limit" terminology because it conflicts in a mild but confusing way with the terminology prevalent in category theory (inverse limits are limits but direct limits are colimits). The category-theoretic terminology instead talks about cofiltered limits and filtered colimits (http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/filtered+limit).

Comment: lim←Z/nZ. can be shown isomorphic to direct product of all Zp p-adics

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is used to denote the [inverse limit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_limit) as opposed to the notation $\displaystyle\lim_{\to}$ which is used to denote the [direct limit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_limit).